# Repast: cannot run the simulation model using the standalone JAR via installation builder

Tags: repast-simphony

I used  installation builder to generate the Jzombie model JAR and install it on my pc. But I could not initialize the model and run it. It reports some errors but I don't know where is actually wrong. I can run the model with no problem in Eclipse.

[image]

Comment: Did the answer below fix your issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to a mismatch between the java version used within Eclipse and the default java version used by your PC. If you are able to adjust your default java to match the one you are using within Eclipse or edit the start_model.bat file to point to the appropriate java version you should be fine.

As an aside, you can look at the content of the warnings and errors that the Error Log panel shows by expanding the window in the bottom part of the panel.